# Related objects reference with custom manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to get the related object references and I want to use a custom manager.

Is there something outside? How I can use a custom manager to get these objects?

```
 b.entry_set.all()
```

E.g

```
b.custom_manager.entry_set.all()
b.entry_custom_manager_set.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been possible since Django 1.7. Say you have a model `Entry` with two managers:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey('Blog', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    
    objects = models.Manager()  # Default Manager
    entries = EntryManager()    # Custom Manager
```

Then you can control which manager you use by passing `manager` to `entry_set`:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
b.entry_set.all() # implicitly use the default manager
b.entry_set(manager='objects').all() # explicitly use the default manager
b.entry_set(manager='entries').all() # explicitly use the entries manager
```

See the docs on [using a custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a ticket is still open for this feature https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3871

Comment: No problem. Keep an eye on future release notes, it looks like this might have been patched but not added to the 1.5 release due to a feature freeze so it might be in 1.6