# How to use custom managers in reverse relations?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

I want to get the related object references and I want to use a custom manager.

I see there has been already a question about it, but its not open anymore. So im creating a new one 
Edit: And its outdated.

This is pretty much what im trying to do:
[Related objects reference with custom manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301532/related-objects-reference-with-custom-manager)

```
b.entry_set.all() # This will use the default Manager
b.custom_manager.entry_set.all() # This should use my custom model manager
```

I see the ticket is closed but i havent found a solution to it yet.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3871

Im using django 1.6.5

Comment: Good question. I'm also looking for more information about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found only this solution:

```
instance.entry_set(manager='custom_manager')
```

Comment: I tried that but all i got was this:
    `TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object is not callable`

You might be using a different django version maybe?

Comment: Maybe.. It's for django 1.7

Comment: This works for me but I would like to know if there is a section in the documentation for this?

Comment: @Omar this is now covered in the docs for [using a custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager)

Comment: Working on Django 3: Use it as:
custom_manager_result_qs = some_model.related_name(manager='my_manager').filter(...). This way you can use multiple managers to fetch related objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.8, you can override the `_default_manager` attribute, which is used for reverse relationships (and direct queries via `objects`).